# How to print table of contents in c++

Tags: c++

I want to print a table of contents like below:

```
1 Data types and expressions
  1.1 Data types in C++
  1.2 Constants
      1.2.1 What are Constants
      1.2.2 Mathematical constant
      1.2.3 Literal constant
  1.3 Variables
      1.3.1 What are variables
      1.3.2 Variable naming rules
  1.4 Operators in C++
  1.5 Arithmetic operators
      1.5.1 Basic rithmetic operators
```

Using class inheritance.
There should be three classes: first title(for example, 1 Data types and ~~ ), second title(1.1 Data types in ~~ ), third title(What are contants).
I am planning to use dynamic array since the book that I want to print might change or I might have to print multiple books. (the number of title could change)

This is my code up to now :

```
class First_Title {
public:
    string first_name;
    int first_num;
    First_Title(string f_name, int f_num) : first_name(f_name), first_num(f_num){};
    void print()
    {
        cout << this->first_name << "/" << this->first_num;
    };

};

class Second_Title : public First_Title {
public:
    string second_name;
    int second_num;
    Second_Title(string f_name, int f_num, string s_name, int s_num) : First_Title(f_name, f_num), second_name(s_name), second_num(s_num){};
};

class Third_Title : public Second_Title {
public:
    string third_name;
    int third_num;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

But I guess this is a wrong code to do it.

What could be the best way to print the table of contents?

Comment: Have an `indent` member variable that tells how many spaces to indent.

Comment: I think that making `Node` and `Graph` classes is also helpful to implement it. If you use `Node` and `Graph` style, you would get the result by `DFS`

Answer (score 1):

This structure will do the work

```
struct node  {
    std::string title;
    std::vector<node> child;
    void print(int idx, string prefix) const {
       cout << prefix << " " << title << std::endl;
       prefix = "  " + prefix;
       int inner_idx = 1;
       for ( auto &c : child ) {
           c.print(inner_idx++, prefix + to_string(inner_idx) + '.');
       }
    };
};
```

link:
https://godbolt.org/z/WazbfK